# Как получить из тега option его содержимое

Tags: php, javascript, select, форма

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: У меня есть форма бронирования отелей, в ней есть селект с номерами (стандартный, люкс и т.д). Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
<form action="обработчик" method="post">
<select id="room" name="room" value="">
<option value="0">Выбрать</option>
        <option value="2300">Стандарт</option>
        <option value="2700">Стандарт (Улучшенный)</option>
        <option value="5000">Люкс (с подиумом)</option>
</select>
/// submit
</form>
```

На этой же странице с формой у меня происходить подсчет цены, именно поэтому у тега option стоят такие значения value. После нажатия на кнопку бронировать, данные поступают в обработчик. Никак не могу вывести в обработчике названия номера. Мне приходят значения value. Как получить значение содержимого выбранного option. Думаю, что в таком случае нужно вытаскивать сначала javascript'ом и каким-то образом отправлять в обработчик, но не выходит. Мучаюсь с этим уже дня 3)

Comment: дайте имя селекту

Comment: имя селекта есть)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, пишите не `value="2300"`, а `value="Стандарт"`

Comment: Нет вы не правильно поняли) убирать числа из value нельзя, ибо они нужны для подсчета стоимости. Я писал об этом)

Comment: То есть надо и цена и название? Используйте разделитель и парсите на сервере `value="2300-Стандарт"`

Comment: Неправильный подход. Цены и названия номеров нужно хранить отдельно, а не в форме. Брать оттуда, где лежат, и подставлять в нужные функции, текст и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант для расчёта стоимости используйте атрибут data-cost.

```
<form action="обработчик" method="post">
   <select id="room" name="room" value="">
      <option value="0" data-cost="0">Выбрать</option>
      <option value="Стандарт" data-cost="2300">Стандарт</option>
      <option value="Стандарт (Улучшенный)" data-cost="2700">Стандарт (Улучшенный)</option>
      <option value="Люкс (с подиумом)" data-cost="5000">Люкс (с подиумом)</option>
   </select>
/// submit
</form>
```

Получить стоимость:

```
var select = document.getElementById("room");
var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-cost');
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, отлично подошло)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#room').change(function(event) {
    //Получаем данные Data-cost
    var cost = $("option[value="+$(this).val()+"]", this).data('cost');
    //Получаем значение value
    var value = $(this).val();
    //Получаем текст межу <option>Текст</option>
    var text = $("option[value="+$(this).val()+"]", this).html();
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!